# Phyiscs behind jumping forward?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, friction

According to me while jumping our leg apply a backward force on the feet and to prevent relative motion static friction acts in forward. As the leg applied  a backward force on feet the feet also apply a forward force on the leg allowing  us to jump forward.
If this is correct then how will i able to apply work energy theorem assuming man as a system and there is a 'x' displacement.
If this is incorrect then whats happening in reality and how can i apply work energy theorem?

Comment: The statis force does no work so there is no work-energy theorem related to that force in this context.

Comment: there is no work done by static friction because of the reason that the force stopped acting while the man was in air?                                                                                                       if yes then assuming there is a trolley ( as a surface where man jumps) then which force work done is responsible for change in kinetic energy of trolley

Comment: The friction is static.  There is no displacement related to this force so there is no work done by the static force.  The work is done by internal forces produces by muscle contraction.

Comment: The only role that friction plays is to allow you to jump at an angle to the vertical. Without friction you could still jump, but every jump would be vertical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you push the ground backwards?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/648724/how-can-you-push-the-ground-backwards)